# Cakephp validation on non-form variables

Tags: cakephp

Was checking out this tutorial "http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html" only seem to explain validating on form fields.

So what If I want to validate params or input data.

If I have this controller, where I want to validate a this "campaignId"?:

```
public function agency($campaignId = null){
    if ($this->request->is('get')){
        $campaignId;
     ...

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP Model Data Validation is validation of the data, regardless of where it comes from.

If you create an array of data, eg:

```
$article = array(
    'title' => 'Pizza is the Best Food on Earth',
    'byline' => 'Dave from StackOverflow',
    'content' => 'Pizza is awesome.  I love it.'
);
```

Then try to save it:

```
$this->Article->save($article);
```

The Model's validation will kick in and validate (or invalidate) the data.

The most common way data is entered is via a form, but - beyond that, validation is not directly tied to using a form(s).